# How to run a spring project

Tags: spring, maven, hsqldb

I need to continue on an existing template project which you can find here:

http://soft.vub.ac.be/soft/_media/edu/aosd/bankingwebstudent.zip

Ive implemented the data and service layer so far but how do you run this project? Since there is no main type as far as I know ... I tried running the banking.deploy.xml by rightclicking -> run on server -> tomcat 6.0 but that didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

From whatever files you've attached, it doesn't seem like its a maven project, since it is missing a pom.xml file. If you want to convert your project into a maven project, just import the project into an IDE (may be Eclipse) as a normal java web application project, and then right click and add a maven pom.xml file.(Please install the maven plugin for eclipse before doing this).Then you could go to the project home folder, and in command prompt, build your project as :

mvn clean install

OR

mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests (in case you want to skip any tests).

Once you build your project copy the war file from the target directory, and copy it into the webapps folder of ApacheTomcat.

Since there is this entry in your web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BankingWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

by default, Spring looks for a configuration file named BankingWeb-servlet.xml, which is there in your application, inside which you have imported the xml file for configuring your controllers.(i.e. banking.web.controller.xml).

Now, say if you fire the following url :

http://    localhost:8080/BankingWeb/login.htm

the flow would be like :

web.xml -> BankingWeb-servlet.xml -> LoginController -> loginSuccess.jsp.

But before all these happens, since a filter is mentioned in the web.xml, the filter will be executed first.

Also, since there is a ContextLoadListener property in the web.xml file, Spring would search for a file named applicationContext.xml, inside which you are importing the banking.deploy.xml. This is how a basic flow occurs. 
Must say that its high time you upgrade to Spring 3.0, and also you haven't used much of Spring in this whole project as of now.

Comment: How do I "build" the project to get the war file? Can someone point me in some reference material? When I do run it on a server I get a 404 page with "requested source is not available".

Comment: once you have a pom.xml ready, go to the home directory of your project, and type the maven install command as mentioned above. Before that,if you are using Eclipse IDE, from the home directory, execute: mvn eclipse:eclipse  and then the mvn clean install command. This would result in a target directory, in which your war file will be formed. Copy this into the Apache Tomcat's webapps directory, and then hit the url.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is a framework that helps you, among other things, manage your servlets.
You need to create a war file from your project and deploy it in tomcat.

You will need to edit your web.xml (in tomcat) by following these instructions:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s02.html

After that HTTP requests for tomcat will be redirected to the spring servlet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Spring setup is coherent and your `web.xml` includes relevant `RequestContextListener`, eg.

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

you can write a small `Launcher` class using Jetty to start the application:

```
public class Launcher
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        Server jettyServer = new Server();
        SocketConnector conn = new SocketConnector();
        conn.setPort( 8080 );
        jettyServer.setConnectors( new Connector[]{ conn } );
        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.setContextPath( "/" );
        context.setWar( "src/main/webapp" );
        jettyServer.setHandler( context );
        jettyServer.start();
    }
}
```

You will need at least this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

but also others if you need eg. JSP and/or JNDI capability.

Hope that helps.

Comment: according to the description there shouldnt be anything added or edited to the project to make it run...